# How To Validate DropDown List in Asp .net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

The List of the month are Already added In Databases. For Adding the salary (Create operation), i have to select the month type from the Drop Down List, if the month is not selected the program should not have to redirect to create action. How Can i validate the Drop Down, Before Routing to Create Action ?

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create","Talab",FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Create","TotalSalary")" class="btn btn-success input-sm">Add New </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">   
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Month.id,     (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["monthType"], "--Select a Month--")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Month.id)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My View Model has following Property

```
public class Salary
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public Nullable<int> month_id { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public virtual Month Month { get; set; }

   public IEnumerable<Month> GetMonths()
   {
        IEnumerable<Month> mat = null;
        mat = this.db.Months.ToList();
        return mat;
   }

}
Public Class Month
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string month { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Salary> Salary { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller Action Index

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Salary salary = new Salary();
        ViewData["monthType"] = salary .GetMonths().ToList().Select(
                 s => new SelectListItem
                 {
                     Text = s.month,
                     Value = s.id.ToString()
                 });

        return View(salary);
    }
```

Comment: As an aside, it is highly recommended you format your code cleanly so people can quickly and accurately understand what you're doing!

Comment: Just use the RequiredAttribute like any other input. The validation doesn't have anything to do with drop-down list or text box or whatever input you use.

Comment: Not It didnot work! I can Redirect to Create Action without Selecting any Value from the Drop Down.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the Create link to be disabled if a month is not set in the drop-down list? Then you will have to validate with javascript.

Comment: Yeah!! Exactly... Please help with this scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dropdownlist should bind to property `month_id` which is `Nullable<int>`, but you have not decorated it with the `[Required]` attribute. It needs to be

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please select a month")]
public Nullable<int> month_id { get; set; }
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.month_id, ....)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.month_id)
```

Side note: You claim your using a view model, but in fact your not. What you have shown is a data model. A view model contains only properties relevant to your view and should never contain method that access your database. Refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

A view model in your case would be

```
public class SalaryViewModel
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select a month")]
  [Display(Name = "Month")] // for use in @Html.LabelFor()
  public Nullable<int> month_id { get; set; }
  public SelectList MonthList { get; set; } // or IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MonthList
}
```

Where you populate the MonthList property in the controller and use it in the view as

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.month_id, Model.MonthList, "--Select a Month--")
```

Comment: What should be added to the Controller ?

Comment: Do your mean to populate the `SelectList`? If so, its just what you currently using to assign `ViewData["monthType"]`

Comment: Your Solution Wont' Give My answer!! But Thank you

Comment: What do you mean wont give you the answer. Read the first paragraph. You binding to a property named `month_id` which is nullable but you don't have the required attribute so anything you select (including the "--Select a Month--" option) IS VALID. It is the CORRECT answer! The side note just points out how you should be doing it.

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Month.id, Model.MonthList, "--Select a Month--") ... Where is month_id... ?? drop down has nothing to do with  month_id..if the  month is selected, the id of that month is copied to month_id which is the property of Salary. otherwise, the Create link should be disabled

Comment: Sorry - typo in my code - it should be `m => m.month_id`

Comment: And is anything wrong on my code?? Usually i used to copy all the property from the model generated by the EF and called it as a view model and all the CRUD operation is done from that Classes.

Comment: Nothing as a piece of code (although declaring `mat` as null initially is pointless, as is the extra overhead of `.ToList()` since all you want is `IEnumerable<Month>`). Its just does not belong in a view model (impossible for example to write unit tests) - it belongs in the controller.

Comment: In this section of Code i want to fetch the list of the month stored in databases. how could i do this ?                                                                                                public class Repository
 {
  public static List<Month> FetchMonths()
  {
   List<Month> months = new List<Month>()
   {
    new Month(){ ID = 1, Name = "January" },
    new Month(){ ID = 2, Name = "February" },
    new Month(){ ID = 3, Name = "March" },
    new Month(){ ID = 4, Name = "April" }
   };
   return months;
  }
 }

Comment: Your Codes on fiddle works fine !! but in my code whenever i press the save button without selecting any value, it generates validation error message but also display "You hit the Controller".. Please help

Comment: First thing to check is that you have the correct scripts, and in the correct order - `jquery{version}.js`, `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`

Comment: Wow!!! Every things work fine now! Thank You Very very much...Would you help again with further Question ?

Comment: Sure, but you will need to ask a new question (not continue this thread). Add a link to it here when your done and I'll have a look  :)

Comment: Sorry!! one more question, Now, how do i Redirect to Create Action after Selecting the Valid Option, and make the month_id available for insertion after the create action is completed.

Comment: I would need to see more code to be sure (which is why you should ask a new question). Your view has `@using(Html.BeginForm("Create","Talab",FormMethod.Post))` so its posting to the `Create()` method. Assuming your using the `SalaryViewModel` as per my answer, If that method is `public ActionResult Create(SalaryViewModel model)` then `model.month_id ` will contain the selected value.

Comment: If it would be possible i would send you a whole file? and you can answer me and i would fix it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902230/system-collections-generic-keyvaluepairstring-system-web-mvc-modelstate-error i have added a new question.. Please have a look!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635218/how-to-detect-the-request-body-is-either-missing-or-broken-in-web-api 
please help!!

Comment: @aakash, The question you linked to cannot be answered because you have not even explained what your doing, e.g. are you sending this object as part of an ajax call. And you have not even shown the controller method.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use required on the model.

```
[Required]
public int id { get; set; }
```

[Validating required selection in DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672289/validating-required-selection-in-dropdownlist)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why are you making `id` nullable when it's required?

Comment: If it's `int` then the `date-val-required` attribute is added by default - a property that is typeof `int` is always required because it cant be null. The `[Required]` attribute is unnecessary unless you want to override the default error message using `ErrorMessage="someMessage"`

Answer (score 1):

Specify the range attribute

```
[Required]
[Range(1, 12, ErrorMessage="Please select a value")]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Source : [MVC3 validation with data-annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530648/mvc3-validation-with-data-annotation)